# ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-react"

Tags: sublimetext, eslint

I work in sublime-text 3 with the following project structure:

```
workdir

--root-project-dirictory

---- src

---- eslint.yml

--project.sublime-project
```

The problem is this: *ESLint* is looking for the `eslint-plugin-react` plugin in `workdir` and not in the `root-project-dirictory`.

As a result I get an error:

```
ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-react".

(The package "eslint-plugin-react" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory "/.../workdir".)

...

The plugin "eslint-plugin-react" was referenced from the config file in "root-project-dirictory / .eslintrc.yml".
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SublimeLinter ESLint couldn't find the plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879118/sublimelinter-eslint-couldnt-find-the-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, ESLint was looking at a parent directory that also had a .eslintrc file. To opt out of ESLint's default cascading behavior and fix `npm run eslint .`, I added `"root": true,` to the top of the .eslintrc in my current working directory.

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#cascading-and-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is this: ESLint is looking for the eslint-plugin-react plugin in workdir and not in the root-project-dirictory.

If `eslint-plugin-react` is included in the root working directory then it should be installed in the root and you can then extend the sub config from the root.

Comment: Happens when your parent directory has .eslintrc or .eslintrc.yml

Answer (score -1):

Until now, I have not found a solution to this problem without changing the structure of the working directory.

As a solution, I use the following:

- create an empty sublime-text project
- add one by one folder to the project, such as "src", "app" ...
- if files are needed in --root-project-dirictory, then add it, but I'm working on the application in separate sublime-text folders of the project

Comment: Please have a look at the question that is pretty much a duplicate of this. It is likely that this is an ESLint v6 problem

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and found the main reason and how to fix:

```
npx eslint . --fix
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 6.1.0.
ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-import".
```

or this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'
```

To fix it run this:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules

$ npm install eslint --save
$ npm install eslint-config-airbnb-base --save
$ npm install eslint-plugin-markdown --save
$ npm install eslint-plugin-import --save

(install all other plugins)

$ npm i
$ npx eslint --version

(should be less than 7)
```

Now, it works:

```
npx eslint . --fix
```

**Reason:**
It seems if libs listed under dev reps, ESLint got updated automatically to 7.0 which is not ready yet. As you can see we had [the same error before on version 6.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879118/sublimelinter-eslint-couldnt-find-the-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

For me, the issue was that I was using eslint globally which does not have that plugin. I used the command `npx eslint ...` then it worked normally.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I did find a `.eslintrc.json` file in the Project Parent folder. After deleting it everything went back to normal.